# OutOfMemory issue with CPU spikes in JBoss 4 web app

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory

we have developed a commercial web app. It is Java Servlet application deployed on JBoss 4. 
Some times, we get OutOfMemory exceptions. We have tried increasing the Heap Size to an extra Gigabyte but we still get the exception. Also, during this exception, we have observed that CPU spikes and ranges from 100% to 900%. Currently we are restarting the JBoss server to resolve the issue.
Can someone help us how to debug this issue?

We have also added the following opts while running the server but the heap file is not being created. Is it the right way? Please help.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/dumps
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how can CPU spike to 900% :-p

Comment: Increasing HeapSpace is never a solution for an application eating memory and not releasing it. You need to see how many big objects are killing your server. To do that use a java profiler.

Comment: 900%: 9 CPUs all doing garbage collection.
Use jvisualvm to see what objects are using your memory. THen you can find the mistake in the code.

Comment: as @NorbertvanNobelen suggested, you can start with jvisualvm. It comes with all JDK versions and is available at <jdk-install-folder>/bin/jvisualvm You can start and attach your jboss VM to see how the heap is being occupied and take occasional dumps to see whats being eating up space. If you have a memory leak then adding up any amount of resources wont help.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off JSP tag pooling. Its a bug in jboss and they have not fixed yet till version 7.
More details on this page : http://bit.ly/1CqbAuD